# The "if" condition not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, if-statement

For some kind of reason, the variable declared in the if condition get's an unused variable and the variable that's going to be used later gets the undeclared variable.  Why is this happening and what's the way to fix it.?

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Josh"];

if ([name isEqualToString:@"Josh"])
{
    NSString *greeting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello Josh"]; //Warning: Unused variable 'greeting'
}
else 
{
    NSString *greeting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name]; //Warning: Unused variable 'greeting'
}
NSLog (@"%@", greeting); //Error: 'greeting' undeclared
```

Comment: there no reason to use `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]` when you do not provide format arguments, use `-[NSString stringWithString:]`. Also, `@"Josh"` is a perfectly valid NSString instance - there's no need to type `NSString *name = [NSString stringWithString:@"Josh"];`, with `NSString *name = @"Josh";` as an equivalent in this case.

Comment: @Justin, @theAmateurProgrammer: There's not much reason to use `stringWithString:`, either. Usually, you should just use the string as it is.

Comment: @Peter Hosey the second sentence of my comment makes this point

Comment: @Justin Oops, yeah. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Peter Hosey no worries. i also read too fast at times. cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should definitely read about [variables scope](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class).

Here's a proper code:

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Josh"];
NSString *greeting = nil;

if ([name isEqualToString:@"Josh"])
{
    greeting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello Josh"];
}
else 
{
    greeting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
}

NSLog (@"%@", greeting);
```

Answer (score 4):

By declaring those `greeting` vars within the `if` and `else` blocks, you are only defining them within that scope. You'll need to define `greeting` before the `if`/`else` blocks, like so:

```
NSString *name = @"Josh";
NSString *greeting = nil;

if ([name isEqualToString:@"Josh"])
{
    greeting = @"Hello Josh";
}
else 
{
    greeting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
}

NSLog (@"%@", greeting);
```

As a general rule: when you declare a variable within a `{`+`}` control block, the variable won't be visible outside that block.